# MYSQL - Like statement not working with special characters

Tags: mysql

I am having an issue with the following:

Inside my table I have the following:

```
ID     Long    Latt    city 
1      n/a     n/a     Newcastle-upon-Tyne 
2      n/a     n/a     Newcastle Upon Tyne 
3      n/a     n/a     Stoke-on-Trent 
4      n/a     n/a     Stoke on Trent
```

If someone enters in the search "Newcastle Upon Type" I want both of them to show. My sql statement is:

```
select * from `properties` where `city` LIKE '%Newcastle Upon Tyne%'
```

But only one shows? But it's a LIKE statement, "Newcastle-Upon-Tyne" and "Newcastle Upon Tyne are similar - So why is only the exact match showing in this instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LIKE comparison is returning TRUE only for that one row.

The LIKE comparison is essentially equivalent to an equality comparison

```
SELECT 'ab d' =    'ab d'  --> TRUE
     , 'ab d' LIKE 'ab d'  --> TRUE
```

The difference is that LIKE supports *two* wildcard characters in the values on the right side.... the percent sign character (`%`) and the underscore character (`_`).  The `%` character matches zero, one or more of any character. The `_` character matches any one single character.

---

Compare the results from

```
 city LIKE 'Newcastle_Upon_Tyne'
 city LIKE 'Newcastle%Upon%Tyne'
```

Both of those would evaluate to true for values of city

```
'Newcastle-Upon-Tyne'
'Newcastle7Upon4Tyne'
```

Additionally, the one with the percent signs would also evaluate to TRUE for values of city such as

```
'NewcastleUpon56789Tyne'
'Newcastle FEE- UponFI Tyne'
```

---

If you want more precise matching than is provided by the LIKE comarison, you could use a regular expression instead..

```
city REGEXP 'Newcastle[ -]Upon[ -]Tyne'
```

This would return TRUE for city values

```
'Newcastle Upon Tyne'
'Newcastle-Upon Tyne'
'Newcastle Upon-Tyne'
'Newcastle-Upon-Tyne'
```

Answer (score 2):

Because a space is not a wildcard character. A space is just like any other letter in a like statement. If you do something like this:

```
select * from `properties` where `city` LIKE '% %'
```

It will find all of the records that contain a space.

If you want any records that contain the words in that order, regardless of the characters between them, you can do this:

```
select * from `properties` where `city` LIKE '%Newcastle%Upon%Tyne%'
```

Comment: would the '_' (single character wildcard) be more accurate? Although I would probably use your answer. :) will delete this comment later

Comment: @RyanVincent I agree the `_` is valid but it depends on the OPs way of approaching these things I think....

Comment: Yes, if  you want exactly one character between each word, use the underscore. It depends on exactly what you want. My answer will find those 3 words with anything in between them or nothing. So `Newcastle--upon--Tyne` and `NewcastleuponTyne` would both be matches, but neither of them would be matches with the underscore.